# findOne() is returning the whole model instead of a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using findOne() to extract a document. On printing the returned value its prints the correct result but on looping over it, it prints the model instead of the original document.
The document in the City table is stored as -

```
{
 _id: 62e135519567726de42421c2,
configType: 'cityConfig'
'16': {
        cityName: 'Delhi',
        metro: true,
        tier1: true
      },
'17': {
        cityName: 'Indore',
        metro: false,
        tier1: false
      }
}
```

The code -

```
const getCities = async () => {
  const cityConfig = await City.findOne({
    configType: "cityConfig"
  });

  console.log("cityConfig - ", cityConfig);
  
  let metroCities = [];

  for(var city in cityConfig) {
    console.log("city - ", city);
    if(cityConfig[city].metro == true) { // throws an error here obviously
      metroCities.push(city);
    }
  }
  return metroCities;

};
```

The ouptut of `cityConfig` is correct, but inside the for loop, its iterating over the model instead of the document.
Output -

```
cityPassConfig -  {
 '16': {
    cityName: 'Nagpur',
    passIssuedCities: false,
    digitalDiscountEnabledCities: false,
    bhopalIndore: false,
    mPanelCitiesForPass: false
  },
  '17': {
    cityName: 'Mumbai',
    passIssuedCities: false,
    digitalDiscountEnabledCities: false,
    bhopalIndore: false,
    mPanelCitiesForPass: false
  },
 _id: 62e288807b59432f87e32a82,
  configType: 'cityPassConfig'
}
city -  $__
city -  isNew
city -  errors
city -  $locals
city -  $op
city -  _doc
city -  $init
city -  db
city -  discriminators
city -  configType
city -  cityId
city -  configData
city -  enabled
city -  lastModifiedby
city -  _id
city -  updatedAt
city -  createdAt
.
.
.
.
```

I want it to just iterate over 16 and 17 (the keys of the object). How to do that? Node version - v14.15.4

Comment: are you using node? if yes then please share the version of node

Comment: This should really be tagged with `mongoose`, as this question is entirely about `mongoose`...

Comment: @Mr.Developer v14.15.4 - Node

Comment: Maybe you need to modify your document to be something like `{_id: 62e135519567726de42421c2, configType:'cityConfig', data:[{16:...},{17:....}]}` and then check inside cityConfig.data

Comment: Mongoose `findOne` query returns a Document, NOT a JS object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Mongoose, so if you want to return the JavaScript object, you should use `lean()` method.

```js
const cityConfig = await City.findOne({ configType: "cityConfig" }).lean();
```

If you don't use `lean()`, Mongoose will hydrate the document. You can read more [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html).

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with your document:

```
{
    _id: 62e135519567726de42421c2,
    configType: 'cityConfig' // There should be a comma here, but not sure if that's affecting anything.
    '16': {
        cityName: 'Delhi',
        metro: true,
        tier1: true
    },
    '17': {
        cityName: 'Indore',
        metro: false,
        tier1: false
    }
}
```

Your `'16'` and `'17'` are siblings with `configType`. You should have it nested inside e.g.

```
{
    _id: 62e135519567726de42421c2,
    configType: 'cityConfig',
    cityConfig: [
        '16': {
            cityName: 'Delhi',
            metro: true,
            tier1: true
        },
        '17': {
            cityName: 'Indore',
            metro: false,
            tier1: false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for keys which are `numbers` only.

```
const cityConfig = await City.findOne({
 configType: "cityConfig",
});

console.log("cityConfig - ", cityConfig);

let metroCities = [];

for (var city in cityConfig) {
 if (!isNaN(city)) {
   console.log("city - ", city);
   if (cityConfig[city].metro == true) {
     // throws an error here obviously
     metroCities.push(city);
   }
 }
}
return metroCities;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Mongoose queries return an instance of the Mongoose Document class, you can find the object in `_doc` of the result.

if you don't need all those info use
[.lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html), it will also make your query faster and less memory intensive.

`const cityConfig = await City.findOne({ configType: "cityConfig" }).lean();`

You can then iterate like you are doing right now either use `.lean()` or try `for(var city in cityConfig._doc)`